# Differentiate Generic Tromino or Tetramino Match vs Specific Shape (Square, Line, L, ect..) in Match-3

Tags: graphics, ui-design, user-experience, visualization, user-interface

This is primarily a user interface question related to match-3 games and visualizing a goal for the player using clear imagery.

I'm interested in having a match-3 game where if you get certain matches it gives you something.

Certain, being a specific shape, vs a generic 3-block (tromino) or 4-block (tetramino).  I have an interest in Pentamino's, there's just a lot of shapes with all the mirrors/rotations.

A specific shape, such as Square, Line, L, Z, T

Visually:

```
// 3 block (tromino)
//    Line(I), L (2 and all mirrors and rotations)
//    xxx, xx
//         x
// 4 block (tetromino) (5)
//    Square(O), Line(I), L, Z, T (5 and all mirrors and rotations)
//    xx, xxxx, xxx,  xx, xxx
//    xx,     , x  , xx ,  x
```

However, showing this to a player as a goal becomes challenging, because the most obvious "generic" 3-block would be a Line, except its also a specific shape.

So then, how to differentiate:

- I need you to get (2) generic 3-block matches
- I need you to get (2) 3-block Line matches

Comment: This seems like an interesting UI problem, but I'd like to make sure I understand what type of goal you're trying to convey to the player. In the example you give is the goal to get: any size 3 I + any size 3 L + any sort of size 4 tetromino?

Comment: In the example, the designer is attempting to differentiate between two different goals for the player.   `Goal 1) Get a (certain #) of 3 block (tromino) matches.  Goal 2)  Get a (certain #) of Line Shape (capital I notation) 3-block matches (L shapes, for example, will not count).`  This becomes far more difficult with 4-block (tetromino) matches, because then there are five (5) different types. (I,Z,L,T,O) from a generic 4-block.